# Hibernate | Null elements in arraylist while getting all entries

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

While fetching all the entries from database it returns an ArrayList with error all elements cannot be null.

But when I fetch query with select one or one + elements, it returns the proper arraylist.

I tried but didn't find any useful working answer.

Thanks,

[image]

```
String String = "from abc rfi " +
                        "where rfi.a=:carrier " +
                        "and rfi.b=:fileStatus " +
                        "and rfi.c=:fileType ";

Query query = session.createQuery(queryString);
query.setParameter("fileStatus", fileStatus.value());
query.setParameter("carrier", carrier.value());
query.setParameter("fileType", fileType);
```

Answer (score 1):

Hibernate may return all elements as null even if a single field of the primary key in the result is null.

Comment: You sure every database field on the table is defined "NOT NULL"? You can possibly troubleshoot by fetching a single row. If it returns good value, then increase the range of rows to find out where exactly it breaks.

Comment: Updated my answer. I did not mention it was the primary key fields that that is not supposed to be null.

Comment: Yes I have done that part all primary key elements are not null, and even i have filled all the data in column then also the same issue arises

Answer (score 0):

Since you said you filled all the data so just another check you can do. In your query, you add the values in where clause -

```
query.setParameter("fileStatus", fileStatus.value());
```

Is `fileStatus` is `enum`? If yes, are you sure you get the expected value from `fileStatus.value()` or data in DB exist with `fileStatus.name()`